# Tranform.Rotate css for print window not working ? JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, rotatetransform

I want to print my data in 90 degree that is cheque but my transform.rotate css style not working here is my html

```
   <div id="content">
        <div id="dvRef"  class="divSquare">1</div>
        <div  id ="dvDate"  class="divSquare">2</div>
        <div style='clear:both'></div>
        <div id="dvWords" class="divSquare">3</div>
        <div id="dvAmount" class="divSquare">4</div>
  </div>
```

JS for print window

```
        var win = window.open('', 'printwindow','height=600,width=800');
        var str = '<html><head><title> alflah</title>';
        str = str + '<style> #content  {     position: relative;   top: 90px;   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);  transform: rotate(90deg);    }      div#dvAmount { position: relative;  left: 218px; } .divSquare{     width:20%; height:10px; margin:4px;  float: left  } div#dvDate {  left: 218px;   position: relative;   top: -16px;  }  </style>';
        str = str + '   </head>';
        $(win.document.head).html(str);
        $(win.document.body).html('<body>' + $("#content").html() + '</body></html>'); 
        win.document.close();
        win.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        win.print();
        win.close();
```

my css for top and alignment work but i need transform.rotate also to be working but it is not working any idea.I am adding js fiddle link

[Link to problem JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzv4pswp/6/)

Comment: wich browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome.. currently

Comment: try position absolute to position it on the page. The rotation always rotates around the middle of the element resulting in content outside the window. For this minimal example it was enough to change the css to: position: absolute; top: 0;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzv4pswp/6/ rotate this

Comment: similar problem but how to apply this in my situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253684/printing-rotated-text-from-web-page